# Java Action listener not working after creating a main menu

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener

My Snake game worked flawlessly before creating a menu. Now that I have created a menu that starts the game upon clicking the "start" button, the game no longer registers to my key presses.

Simple manager working as a controler:

```
public class GameManager {

    public GameManager() {
        new mainMenu();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GameManager();
    }
}
```

Newly implemented main menu class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class mainMenu extends JFrame{
    private final int WIDTH = 300;
    private final int HEIGHT = 300;
    private final int BUTTON_HEIGHT = 30;
    private final int BUTTON_WIDTH = 60;
    private final int SPACING = 10;
    private String title = "Jody Snake";
    Font smallText = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 14);
    Font titleText = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 30);
    JLabel titleLabel;
    JPanel buttonPanel;
    JButton playButton;
    JButton readMeButton;
    JButton quitButton;

    public mainMenu() {
        mainMenuGUI();
    }

    private void mainMenuGUI(){
        this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        titleLabel = new JLabel("SNAKE", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        titleLabel.setFont(titleText);
        this.add(titleLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        playButton = new JButton("PLAY");
        playButton.setFont(smallText);
        playButton.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        playButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        buttonPanel.add(playButton);
        playButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                mainMenu.super.remove(buttonPanel);
                mainMenu.super.remove(titleLabel);
                mainMenu.super.add(new gameBoard());
                mainMenu.super.pack();
            }
        });

        readMeButton = new JButton("READ ME");
        readMeButton.setFont(smallText);
        readMeButton.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        readMeButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        buttonPanel.add(readMeButton);


        quitButton = new JButton("QUIT");
        quitButton.setFont(smallText);
        buttonPanel.add(quitButton);
        quitButton.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        quitButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        this.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        quitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });

        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

Relevant methods from Pre-existing game class:

```
     public gameBoard() {
        super();
        createGameBoard();

    }

    private void createGameBoard() {

        addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
        setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        setFocusable(true);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(B_WIDTH, B_HEIGHT));
        loadImages();
        runGame();
    }
    private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

            int key = e.getKeyCode();

            if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) && (!rightDirection)) {
                leftDirection = true;
                upDirection = false;
                downDirection = false;
            }

            if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) && (!leftDirection)) {
                rightDirection = true;
                upDirection = false;
                downDirection = false;
            }

            if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) && (!downDirection)) {
                upDirection = true;
                rightDirection = false;
                leftDirection = false;
            }

            if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) && (!upDirection)) {
                downDirection = true;
                rightDirection = false;
                leftDirection = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you use that `TAdapter` before? If it's supposed to be usd by the game, then you should the code for the game itself, not the menu.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that your key events are lost in the event chain. Since your JFrame is the top most container, all the key events are being trapped here and not getting re-routed to your game board (I am assuming it's another container). I would recommend adding a key listener at the main menu, and re-route the key events to your game board.

Comment: You should not be using a KeyListener. Instead you should be using `Key Bindings`. See [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for more information and working examples.

Comment: Thanks! any tips as to how to implement that?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. You may have already found the answer, but, if I were going to do it, I would make mainMenu implements KeyListener, and in the GameBoard class, move the keyPressed event handler out of TAdapter. Then in the new keyPressed event handler in mainMenu, call keyPressed function in the gameboard, and pass the key argument. Hope this helps.